# What is the best way to get to offline client-side media storage with Meteor?

Tags: media, meteor, offline

I am unsure of the mongolitedb persistence lifecycle on the client-side. Is it possible to store binary data in there and later reference in html? Or perhaps the best way is to use html5 persistence through localstorage. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The amplify package gives a nice interface for localStorage. Minimongo doesn't persist anything on the client. It's only stored in memory. If you want to persist some of the documents in local storage you'll need to do it yourself for now.